# Type declaration for a function that returns a concrete class constructor

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {
} 

class Foo extends AbstractFoo {
}

class Bar {
    getFooConstructor(): typeof AbstractFoo {
       return Foo;
    }
}

let bar = new Bar();
let FooConstructor = bar.getFooConstructor();
let foo = new FooConstructor();
```

It fails to compile with the following error:

> error TS2511: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.

This is not unexpected since `getFooConstructor` is declared as returning an `AbstractFoo` constructor - i.e. an abstract constructor.

How can I type `getFooConstructor` return value so that TypeScript compiler understand that it returns a concrete constructor that extends `AbstractFoo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that typescript will remember in the type of the class (ie `typeof AbstractClass`) that the constructor is of an abstract class and thus can't be invoked.

The simplest solution is to use a constructor signature instead:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {
} 

class Foo extends AbstractFoo {
}

class Bar {
    getFooConstructor(): new ()=> AbstractFoo {
      return Foo;
    }
}

let bar = new Bar();
let FooConstructor = bar.getFooConstructor();
let foo = new FooConstructor();
```

While this will work, if you also need to access static member on the class you can't (`getFooConstructor` returns a constructor that returns something derived from `AbstractFoo` not the actual class itself). You can achieve this if you derive an interface from the abstract class type, this will erase the abstractness of the constructor and allow us to both call the constructor and still access all static members:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {
  static m(): void { }
}
type AbstarctFooClass = typeof AbstractFoo;
interface AbstractFooDerived extends AbstarctFooClass { }

class Foo extends AbstractFoo {
}

class Bar {
  getFooConstructor(): AbstractFooDerived {
    return Foo;
  }
}

let bar = new Bar();
let FooConstructor = bar.getFooConstructor();
FooConstructor.m()
let foo = new FooConstructor();
```

Comment: you were so fast to answer that I was not able to mark as answered until a few minutes ago :D